# Keep track of different groups of contacts

Tags: contact

What would you recommend for entering internal (those contacts who are our volunteers or staff members) vs. external contacts from our clients?  We want to keep track of these three types of groups: Our own staff members; Our clients; and the Companies (like Salesforce) that are providing the services/resources that we need to produce our services/products.

Answer (score 1):

Both on contact and account you could introduce a **specific type picklist** that allows you to define the type of record you're dealing with (Volunteer, Staff, External contact, Client).

If these separate types also require different data or fields to be shown, you could combine this with **record types**.

Answer (score 0):

One caveat with Record Types is that a given Contact can only ever have one record type.  This can get tricky when you have a Volunteer who is also a Donor and a Vendor.  In this case, we recommend using a series of check-boxes. (not ideal, but it works.)